# Android4.2 multi-user and download

Tags: android

In Android4.2 was a new attribute **multi-user**.

I found the file path was problem When I Download some media ;

example:

When I download a picture form website,this line was the useful log info.

`I/DownloadThread( 1306): mInfo.mHint = file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/girl.jpg`

However,I can't find the **0** directory under */storage/emulated/* Use **adb shell**

That means,I can't use this path */storage/emulated/0/Download/girl.jpg* with C/C++ open function

Android download file step by step :

1. Browser get the information about what we needed to download(DownloadHandler.java)
2. Browser trigger the DownloadManagerService inset the information to *downloads.db*
3. When the *downloads.db* change,to new a new Downloadthread to Download the file!

Question:

1. Why exist **/storage/emulated/0/** directory (multi-user?),Why could I find it with **adb shell** ?
2. is **/storage/emulated/0/** rather than **/storage/sdcard0/** or **/storage/sdcard1/**,why?
3. Android4.1 VS Android4.2 with the different branch Environment.UserEnvironment(int userId)(Environment.java)

Thanks

CaoPeng